# Simulate sklearn logistic regression predict_proba with only coefficients and intercept

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, softmax, sigmoid

I will create dummy data and train sklearn Logistic regression on it. Then I would like to get the output of `predict_proba` but only with own `coef_` and `intercept_` calculation, but the results are different. The setting is following:

```
X = [[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,2,0]]
y = [0,0,0,1,1,2] 

# Fit the classifier
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5, multi_class="ovr", class_weight="balanced")
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Then I will simply use the knowledge about sigmoid and softmax to get output:

```
softmax([
         expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[0]) + clf.intercept_[0]),
         expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[1]) + clf.intercept_[1]),
         expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[2]) + clf.intercept_[2])
])
```

But it will return different values then

```
clf.predict_proba([[0,2,0]])
```

`array([[0.281399  , 0.15997556, 0.55862544]])` in opposite to `array([[0.29882052], [0.24931448], [0.451865  ]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replicate the calculation of the predicted probabilities using the estimated parameters as follows:

```py
from sklearn import linear_model
from scipy.special import expit, softmax
import numpy as np

# Data
X = [[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,2,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,2,0]]
y = [0,0,0,1,1,2]

# Classifier
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5, multi_class="ovr", class_weight="balanced")
clf.fit(X, y)

# Predicted probabilities
print(clf.predict_proba([[0,2,0]]))
#[[0.281399 0.15997556 0.55862544]]

# Recalculated predicted probabilities without softmax
prob1 = np.array([expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[0]) + clf.intercept_[0]),
                  expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[1]) + clf.intercept_[1]),
                  expit(np.dot([[0,2,0]], clf.coef_[2]) + clf.intercept_[2])]).reshape(1, -1)

print(prob1 / np.sum(prob1))
#[[0.281399 0.15997556 0.55862544]]

# Recalculated predicted probabilities with softmax
prob2 = np.log(prob1)

print(softmax(prob2))
#[[0.281399 0.15997556 0.55862544]]
```